# Lyx does not recompile the PDF in any PDF viewer

Tags: lyx, pdf, update

I am running Lyx 2.3.6 for Mac, combined with TexStudio and Adobe Acrobat Reader DC as pdf viewer, under macOS Catalina, version 10.15.7.

The problem is that when I change something in the Lyx document and then print the PDF in the viewer to see the printed changes (for example by using command+T or command+D), the pdf does not update. I need to close the pdf and open it again to see the changes.

If I use Preview or TeXShop as pdf-viewer, the problem remains.

Can anyone help me to find a way to update the pdf directly in the pdf viewer, by using the commands above, and without having to close the file and open it again to have it updated according to the changes I made in Lyx?

Comment: For me (on Ubuntu with Okular), it works as you wished it works without any changes. It is a feature for the PDF viewer to be "watching" the file to see if it changes and update its view accordingly. All LyX does is to overwrite the old file. The PDF viewer should take care of the rest (triggered by the action of seeing that the file changed).

Comment: It is known that Acrobat Reader locks pdf files. It should not be used aas a viewer with latex as long long as you don't have the final pdf.

Comment: To Bernand: ok thanks for the info, but my problem remains if I change pdf viewer.
To scottkosty: Thanks, I take your comment as saying that I should change settings in the pdf viewer. Any suggestion of what in particular I should change or look for?